# Get data from mysql database on date selection using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to fetch data from a MySQL database relevant to the selected `date_time`.

I have extracted the `date_time` from the database and displayed it on a page and now the thing I want to do is that "When I select a date the data on that date should be display without refreshing the page".

Answer (score 0):

you have to create an other .php page containing calling your date_time and call it in ajax after ward.

your ajax request should looks like :

```
    $("#Button_get_date").onclick ( function () {
             $("#div_to_display").load("/date.php", {"date= (#optiondate#.val));
      })
```

the other page php should contain

```
$data = $ddb ->query("select * from tableinfodate where date = ".$_POST["date"].");
```

after i think you know what to do but remember to make your display in your in  the loaded page.

have a look at the function load :http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_load.asp and also at GET and POST method in php. More over i think it is better to try hard on js before trying to do loaded function as this one.
I hope it helps a bit.

Comment: thank you Armand for your reply... I have this code to display all the date available in the db.. <tr>
<td align="center"><label for="date">Select Date:</label></td>
<td>
<select>
<?php
$querydate = "SELECT * FROM tbl_ecg WHERE pid='$pid'";
 if($query_run= mysql_query($querydate)){
              while($row= mysql_fetch_array($query_run)){
    $date = $row['date_time'];
    echo "<option>".$date;
    echo "</option>";
     }
 }
?>
</select>
</td>
<td><input name="Continue" value="date" type="submit" ></td>
When I select a date the data on that date should be display.. thanks

Comment: i think the easyest <way to do it with jquery is to create an other PHP page containing the request you want:

Comment: $data = $ddb ->query("select * from tableinfodate where date = ".$_POST["date"].");